# Move content of each directory to a new subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I have a directory that contains a large number of folders, each of which has varying content. For each of these folders, I need to create a subfolder inside of it with the name `old.0`, and copy all of the folder's contents into the new subfolder.

Graphically, I want this:

```
Directory
> Subfolder1
> > Files1
> Subfolder2
> > Files2
```

To become this:

```
Directory
> Subfolder1
> > old.0
> > > Files1
> Subfolder2
> > old.0
> > > Files2
```

Is there an easy (command line) solution for this, or am I better off going through each folder manually?

I'm definitely no [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) expert, so a step-by-step solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for general ubuntu/linux help. try askubuntu.com

Comment: Could just as easily have been a [tag:linux] question, nothing [tag:ubuntu] specific about it.

Comment: My apologies, is there a way to remove the Ubuntu tag? If not I will just delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute following [find](/questions/tagged/find) command:

```
find Directory -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d  -exec bash -c ' mv "$0" "old.0" && mkdir "$0" && mv "old.0" "$0"' {} \;
```

Explanation:

- `find Directory -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` look for directories in `Directory` but don't descend in subdirectories.
- `-exec` for each dir execute following command (name of dir is stored in `{}` and is supplied to `bash -c` as argument).
- `mv "$0" "old.0` put found dir in temp directory (rename).
- `&& mkdir "$0"` if move successful, create new dir with old dir name.
- `&& mv "old.0" "$0"` and move new dir to new one with the original name.

Example usage:

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ ls
$ mkdir a b c && touch a/a b/b c/c
$ ls */*
a/a  b/b  c/c
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d  -exec bash -c ' mv "$0" "old.0" && mkdir "$0" && mv "old.0" "$0"' {} \;
$ ls */*/*
a/old.0/a  b/old.0/b  c/old.0/c
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But unfortunately I get the following error: " find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

find: missing argument to `-exec' "

Comment: Yes, I was too hasty. Try now please.

Comment: I still get the same error, and also one about -mindepth, and also the following:

mv: inter-device move failed: ‘./dir/sub1' to ‘/tmp/.old.0/sub1’; unable to remove target: Is a directory

Comment: It might be worth noting that the directory is on a secondary hard drive, though all of the folders we are concerned with are on the same drive.

Comment: Haha, now it deletes everything in the subfolders. Good thing I made a copy first.

Comment: Are you sure, create an empty directory and follow the example, are you getting different output?

Comment: Hmm, I must've been using an old version of your command. It works now. Thanks so much!!

Comment: No problem, be sure to check out the man pages of the commands you encounter, e.g. `man find` and perhaps check some tutorials. They can be quite handy!